# what is this saying in python

Tags: python

`map(tuple, map(lambda row: [float(row[0]), int(row[1]), parse(row[2])], res))`

Can someone help me with the syntax here? I'm trying to understand specifically what `tuple` and `lambda` is referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's easier to follow you could rewrite this a few times, from

```
map(tuple, map(lambda row:
    [float(row[0]), int(row[1]), parse(row[2])], res))
```

to

```
map(lambda row: (float(row[0]), int(row[1]), parse(row[2])), res)
```

to

```
[(float(row[0]), int(row[1]), parse(row[2])) for row in res]
```

That doesn't really answer your question, but I thought it was easier to read ;)

Answer (score 2):

`tuple()` is a constructor for a "tuple" object, that can convert a list (or other sequence object) to a tuple.

For example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> tuple(a)
(1, 2, 3)
```

When used in your example, it converts the result of each `lambda` expression from a list to a tuple. It seems a bit redundant, because the following should be equivalent:

```
map(lambda row: (float(row[0], int(row[1], parse(row[2])), res)
```

Note the use of `()` parentheses instead of `[]` square brackets which creates a tuple rather than a list.

Comment: why would someone want to do this

Comment: Tuples are immutable objects (cannot be modified after they're created) and therefore can be used, for instance, as dictionary keys.